# Can't multiply a variable with the generator of a vector

Tags: sage

This is my code:

```
sage: Q = QuadraticForm(ZZ,1,[1])                                                                                                                                  
sage: Cl.<x> = CliffordAlgebra(Q)                                                                                                                                  
sage: a = var('a')                                                                                                                                                 
sage: a*x
```

And it errors as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-c166ddc995fe> in <module>
----> 1 a*x

/var/tmp/sage-9.4-current/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sage/structure/element.pyx in sage.structure.element.Element.__mul__ (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:12205)()
   1513             return (<Element>left)._mul_(right)
   1514         if BOTH_ARE_ELEMENT(cl):
-> 1515             return coercion_model.bin_op(left, right, mul)
   1516 
   1517         cdef long value

/var/tmp/sage-9.4-current/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce.pyx in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel.bin_op (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce.c:11708)()
   1246         # We should really include the underlying error.
   1247         # This causes so much headache.
-> 1248         raise bin_op_exception(op, x, y)
   1249 
   1250     cpdef canonical_coercion(self, x, y):

TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for *: 'Symbolic Ring' and 'The Clifford algebra of the Quadratic form in 1 variables over Integer Ring with coefficients: 
[ 1 ]'
```

How can I multiply `x` with a variable scalar `a`?

Comment: One option would be to define a polynomial ring and use `a` for the indeterminate: `F.<a> = Cl[]`. Then `a*x` will be defined. The answer may depend on what you're hoping to do with `a`, though.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri @JohnPalmieri I wish to write `sage: (a*x+b*y)^2` and have it output `a^2+b^2`. Your method works for one variable (I just tried it), but I cannot make it work for two. I have tried `F.<a,b> = Cl[]`, and `F.<a> = Cl[]` followed by `F.<b> = Cl[]`. It doesn't work if I mix and match `a` with `b` in the same expression. Here `a` and `b` are elements of a field, and `x` and `y` are generators of the algebra.

Comment: Not perfect, but you can do `F.<a> = Cl[]` and then `G.<b> = F[]`. Then if your `Cl` has two generators `x` and `y`, you should be able to compute `(a*x+b*y)^2`. This is not perfect because polynomial rings in Sage should be defined with commutative coefficients, which this `Cl` isn't.

Comment: In a better world, something like this would work: `F.<a.b> = QQ[]` and followed by `Cl.tensor(F)`.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Hey it works; I am actually working with Clifford algebra of 4 dimensions... so I need to repeat this 16 times?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Here is the code, if it can save someones' time: `reset();Q = QuadraticForm(ZZ,4,[1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,-1]);Cl.<t,x,y,z> = CliffordAlgebra(Q);A.<a> = Cl[];B.<b> = A[];C.<T> = B[];D.<X> = C[];E.<Y> = D[];F.<Z> = E[];G.<B01> = F[];H.<B02> = G[];I.<B03> = H[]; J.<E12> = I[]; K.<E13> = J[]; L.<E23> = K[]; M.<V0> = L[]; N.<V1> = M[]; O.<V2> = N[]; P.<V3> = O[];`
Then: `M=a+T*t+X*x+Y*y+Z*z+B01*t*x+B02*t*y+B03*t*z+E12*x*y+E13*x*z+E23*y*z+V0*x*y*z+V1*t*y*z+V2*t*x*z+V3*t*x*y+b*t*x*y*z`

Comment: That's annoying, but I'm glad it's working. Maybe a loop could automate it a bit.